# Lead conversion in lightning UI

Tags: trigger, lightning-experience

We have a trigger in place which takes care of Lead conversion (we had to do this for certain customization requirements). It works fine in Classic version but gets hung-up in lightning UI. If we refresh/reload the page, then it lands on converted lead page. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did u check the debug logs ?? you might get some hint there

Comment: Oh yeah, as I mentioned, it works just fine in Classic version. Infact, in LIghtning UI too. The only problem is the page not moving from in-progress state on its own.