# Lightning UI - error after automatic lead conversion by trigger

Tags: trigger, lightning-experience, lead-conversion

Having a trigger to check if tasks/activities of a lead, to match a conditions then we do auto-convert the lead.

**On Salesforce classic, everything just go fine as expected.**

Unfortunately, Lightning Experience got an error (below image) happen when user try to add activity on (directly on Lead details page) and match our condition that need is auto-convert. The trigger just worked fine, but the Lightning UI got error. (if we do refresh the page, thing just fine)

(I have check in browser console there are no any error or warning log)

similar unsolved issues:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005JZtIAM
- [Lead conversion in lightning UI](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/99054/14880)

[image: error after lead converted]

Comment: The error id is literally the most important part of what's going on. We can't really help you without it.

Comment: Thanks, I tested few times got difference:  Error ID: 2066332479-35697 (-338472869), Error ID: 623474611-33376 (-338472869)

Comment: The last number (-338472869) is a unique identifier for the issue at hand (e.g. if I tried your code in my org, I'd get the same error code). You might want to contact support, but I'll check my resources, too.

Comment: @sdfcfox, tested with another org same issue Error ID: 1611077620-282856 (-1865506895). So that mean this is Salesforce bug ?

Comment: Yes. Kind of surprised it came up with a different number, but it might be pod-based. Still, I would contact support and give them that number. They would be able to tell you more. Lightning still has a lot of bugs to work out.